# Normally i run on command line : python main.py image/ archive/ True , so how can i run on tkinter gui

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code, Thanks everybody.

```
import subprocess
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.image = "image/"
        self.archive = "archive/"

    def create_widgets(self):

        tk.Button(self, text="Run", command=self.run_face_recognition).pack(fill=tk.X)
        tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.master.destroy).pack(fill=tk.X)


    def run_face_recognition(self):
        subprocess.run([sys.executable, "main.py","--image/", "--archive/",  self.image,  self.archive, "args..."])

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would expect the `--image` and `--archive` flags to be immediately followed by the associated value - rather than two flags in a row, followed by two values in a row.

Comment: Please put the question in the question text. The title is supposed to be a brief summary.

Comment: If you don't normally use `--` before `image/` and `archive/`, why did you add them here?

Comment: @Barmar, I tried removing the -- and the result was this: "main.py: error: unrecognized arguments: archive/ args...".

Comment: @jasonharper, it seems to work, but what about True or False, do you know how to add them.

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks for the input, this is my first time asking something on this great forum.

Comment: Just add `'True'` to the list in `subprocess.run`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use `--image` and `--archive` when running the command by hand, you don't need them here.

Just add `True` as another argument in the list.

```
    def run_face_recognition(self):
        subprocess.run([sys.executable, "main.py",  self.image,  self.archive, "True"])
```